# @users.each do |user| --- Is there a way to do this for multiple objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm currently doing:

```
@users.each do |user|
```

Given I have @users, @users1, @users2

Is there a way to do:

```
[@users, @users1, @users2].each do |user|
```

Having the each loop go through all the objects?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have `@users`, `@users1` and `@users2` in the first place?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can concatenate the arrays and iterate the result:

```
(@users + @users1 + @users2).each do |user| 
  ...
end
```

It may be tempting to use flatten, but you should be careful with it.  A simple no-arguments `flatten` call doesn't behave the way you expect if any elements of any array are arrays themselves:

```
users, users1, users2 = [1,2],  [ [3,4], [5,6] ], [ 7,8]
puts [users,users1,users2].flatten.inspect
# Will print [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
# Two small arrays are smashed!!!
```

However, as [jleedev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19750/jleedev) suggests in one of the comments, `flatten` function in Ruby may accept an integer argument that defines the maximum level the arrays will be smashed to, so:

```
puts [users,users1,users2].flatten(1).inspect
# Will print [1, 2, [3, 4], [5, 6], 7, 8]
# Just as planned.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[@users,@users1,@users2].flatten.each do |user|
```

Comment: This will not work as expected, if elements in any of these three arrays are arrays themselves.

Comment: @Pavel Technically true, but unlikely given the names of the arrays

Comment: `.flatten(1)` flattens just one level.

Answer (score 3):

Various techniques:

```
# Concatenate
(@users+@users1+@users2).each{ ... }

# Splat (Ruby 1.9 only)
[*@users,*@users1,*@users2].each{ ... }

# Interleave them
@users.zip( @users1, @users2 ).each{ |u,u1,u2| ... }
```

Comment: I perfer the second one in similar cases.

Comment: @fl00r Well, it depends on if you need this functionality, I suppose.